# Using thousands Static cells uitableviewcells

Tags: ios, memory, uitableview

I am using  static `UITableViewVell`s to manually put text in labels inside cells. Because i am going to use roughly 3000+ static cells, i am concern about memory issues. Can anyone advise if their would be any memory issues if do that Or how can i avoid it?

Many thanks

Comment: Why? Why not implement a proper table view that displays the appropriate label from an array as the table view is scrolled?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Basically my project is audio synch cells where each cells got highlighted with audio background recitation. I created objects of each static cell and because there would be thousands of objects i will create, i am worried by memory issues

Comment: @dasdom I am literally coping the text from the book and pasting it into the cells labels. It takes a lot of time to do it and i don't want app to crash after i done with all copying pasting

Comment: @Asif you can create it with reusable cells without any problems. You need to create array of strings once and than fill labels in reusable cells with this strings.

Comment: DO NOT copy the book text into static cells. Copy the text into a plist file or a text file. Then create a normal table view that displays the data from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Terrible idea. Static cells are retained and there is no reuse. The internal implementation of the static data source just holds an array of rows, which have a table view cell object.

I suggest you create a model where you can create 3000 backing objects, which include the necessary data to display, and reuse cells as needed.

Comment: The reason i am using static cells because i have a book and i want to display each sentence inside a static cell so i can highlight it with audio recitation. Do you think 3000+ static cell would create memory issues?

Comment: Yes, there will be memory issues. Put the sentences into an Array (or read from a file into an array) and simply assign the text of the cell based on the row you're given. No need to make static cells and will lake you more time and effort to create a faulty app than to do it as per the standard. As an array you could add or subtract strings much easier than to revise the UI every time.

Comment: @Thank you Scottdev, can you refer me somewhere where i can learn about extracting file data into array. I am fairly new to iOS development so it would be helpful